# Wireshark wifi traffic not fully listed under monitor mode under OrangePi(Lubuntu)

Tags: wireshark, network-monitoring, orange-pi

I‘m trying to monitor traffics under wifi, And I use both a mac and a lubuntu installed Wireshark, and after I enable monitor mode start listening, the amount of lubuntu packs is far less than Mac (10x less)

1. Does this happen since the CPU or net card things(other hardware things?) or just because of different Wireshark?
2. Is there any other way to identify this cause? (maybe with some other tool or commands)

added:

maybe related to the channel of wifi, but I config wifi to channel 7 and set the lubuntu monitor channel with

```
iwconfig wlanxx channel 7
```

but still, I can't get sniffer traffic under lubuntu but full of them under mac

seems lubuntu only could get the broadcast pack (like arp) and 802.11 Protocol Pack

I'm guessing this due to the bad configuration or implementation of wireless net card

Comment: This is not really about programming, maybe try asking in a different SE forum.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably just more activity on the Mac. I don't know your precise configuration, but if you have a browser open on the Mac and nothing on the lubuntu, then there will be a difference in the amount of network traffic.

1. There is not really a reason for network traffic to change significantly because of hardware. Configuration can play a role though. If ipv4 and ipv6 are enabled, address resolution packets will be double as if only one is. If Arp cache is set to expire fast, there will also be more Arp traffic.
2. To identify the cause, look at what wireshark is telling you. What packets are there on both machines ? what packets are unique to the Mac ? Have a look at protocols, destination IPs and port numbers, they are the main clue to tell you what is happening.

Comment: I'm capturing the traffic in the air with Wifi Monitor Mode

Comment: Oops I missread that sorry. In Monitor mode it is possible that hardware has an effect. Maybe your wireless card on your mac can be at the same time in monitor mode and managed mode. Could you check that ?

Comment: Also, what do you expect to see (and see on your Mac) ? Are the Wifi networks you want to monitor open ?

Comment: it seems my lubuntu only sniffer the broadcast package (like arp / 802.11 Protocol things), so I guess the Monitor Mode just not work well under this system with this wireless card :(

Comment: If the wifi networks use security, this is actually the normal behaviour. But then there is the question of why the Mac sees more

Comment: I've tried with no password wifi (I know the security wifi traffic should decrypt with 4 handshake thing), Just guessing the vendor give me a fake(not fully) Monitor Mode of the since it's cheap :) anyway, thanks for those advice

Answer (score 0):

It seems due to router's setting( wifi channel and mode(802.11xx))

using channel hopping Tech, For capturing as much as possible packages while hopping through multiple channels

And maybe trying some advanced monitor wireless net card for various mode(802.11xx) and 2.5G/5G supporting